# getting decrypted message from RSA_public_decrypt?

Tags: openssl

I signed/encrypted a message in buffer with RSA_sign().

When I decrypt the buffer with RSA_public_decrypt(), the returned value is a digest (X509_SIG) and is not the decrypted message.

I want to get the  message from the digest.  In older OpenSSL releases I would call

```
// covert raw signature buffer into a digest
X509_SIG sig = d2i_X509_SIG(NULL, signature, signature_size); 
// display every byte in the message
// Unfortunately, I'm accessing X509_SIG fields.
for (i = 0; i < sig->digest->length; i++) {
    printf("byte #%d is %.2x\n", sig->digest->data[i]); 
}
```

But OpenSSL made changes and I no longer have access to the fields of X509_SIG.

How do I get the decrypted message?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - This appears to be a programming question, and programming questions are off-topic here even if they are about cryptography related software. Programming questions belong on stackoverflow; I can migrate this there for you.

Comment: (1) `d2i_X509_SIG` returns `X509_SIG *` (pointer) not `X509_SIG` (which as you say is opaque in OpenSSL 1.1.0+). (2) you can recover the _digest_ from a PKCS1v1.5 signature, if that's what you have; you can't ever recover the message from the digest; that's the whole purpose of a crypto hash/digest -- but normally you are _given_ the message with its signature (3) if you want the digest from a v1.5 sig without breaking opacity in 1.1.0+, which isn't hard, either do real DER parsing, or strip the fixed prefix(es) described in rfc8017 9.2 et pred, or just take the last digestsize bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This works for OpenSSL v1.1.1 using @[dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085)'s suggestion about the last digestsize bytes.

If the call to `RSA_public_decrypt` looks like

```
decrypt_size = RSA_public_decrypt(encrypted_len, encrypted_buf, to, rsa, padding);
```

then

```
const EVP_MD *md = EVP_sha1();
unsigned int length= EVP_MD_size(md);
// skip over digest header to get to data
unsigned char *data = to + decrypt_size - length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("byte #%d is %.2x\n", data[i]); 
}
```